# Is there any way to convert JSON String to query String in android?

Tags: android, json, query-string

I am stuck at converting a Json string into query string.

Actually, I want to create query string and from that query string I'll generate a SHA hash and set it in header to send to the server.

Please help!

Comment: what do you mean with "query string"? Something like "SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ..."?

Comment: JSON = { one: 'first', two: 'second' }

Query String = ?one=first&two=second

QueryString is that we pass inURL somthing like. www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2

Answer (score 3):

Is your JSON String currently stored in a JSONObject? If not, this would be the best place to start. Something like this:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(returnedString);
String firstValue= json.get(firstKey);
String secondValue = json.get(secondKey);
```

//And then construct your query string using the obtained values

**Edit**

Generic Method as suggested below...

Something like this:

```
public String getQueryString(String unparsedString){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(unparsedString);
    Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
    sb.append("?"); //start of query args
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append("=");
        sb.append(json.get(key);
        sb.append("&"); //To allow for another argument.

    }

    return sb.toString();
```

If you have more questions regarding JSONObject parsing in Android [these docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) are very helpful

Comment: Thanks, but i need generic class for all kind of parsing.
In this way i have to parse each and every key of JSON. 

I need to convert it into query string that have predefined rules so i don't want to parse one by one.

Comment: you could always create a method for this parsing and pass as a method parameter the keys of the values you need for your query string and it will be more generic

Answer (score 1):

On Android :

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(url_string);
uri.getQueryParameter("para1");
```

On Android, the Apache libraries provide a Query parser:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html and http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html